# Nested Linked List

Tags: c++, nested-lists

I can't seem to find the error which cheating segmentation fault:11

**GIST of code: Main linked list to have alphabets and nested linked list in each alphabet to have words and meanings**

Node2 is supposed to be inside Node ceasing a nested linked list.
Is there something wrong in the node classes or inn the linked list function.
the head of the primary list is null right now

```
class node2
{
public:
    string Word;
    string Meaning;
    node2 *next;
    node2(string word,string meaning)
    {
        Word = word;
        Meaning=meaning;;
        next = NULL;
    }
    node2();
};
class node
{
public:
    char data;    //alphabet
    node *next;
    node(char value)
    {
        data = value;
        next = NULL;
    }
    node2 *innernode=NULL;
    
};
/*----
----
---
---*/
void insertWord(string word, string meaning)
    {
        char alpha = word[0];
        //cout << alpha << endl;
        node *trav = head;
        while (trav != NULL && trav->data != alpha)
        {
            trav = trav->next;
        }
        //cout << trav->data;
        node2* newnode = new node2(word,meaning);
        trav->innernode = newnode;
        trav->innernode->next = NULL;
        //sort_inner();
    }
```

Comment: **Node2 is supposed to be inside Node CREATING a nested linked list. **

Comment: In `insertWord`, after the `while` loop, what is `trav` when the char is not found?

Comment: I don't get it, I have already put head as null at first, before adding on to any. is that what ur saying?

Comment: When the letter is not found then `trav == nullptr` after the `while` loop, so when you try `trav->innernode = newnode;` it will crash since you can't dereference a null pointer.

Comment: Unless you are pre-filling the list with all the letters. In that case please create a [mre].

Comment: im not profiling and leaving it to the user, can help me to fix it because I just can't understand rn. what can I change here

Comment: IMHO, you should have an array of 26 pointers to `node2`.  Convert the letter to upper case or lower case.  Subtract 'a' or 'A' from the letter to get the index  for the array.  Faster and easier than using a list for the letter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where `head` comes from (global variable?), but you need to make sure `trav` is not null after the loop:

```
void insertWord(string word, string meaning)
{
    char alpha = word[0];

    node *trav = head;
    while (trav && trav->data != alpha) {
        trav = trav->next;
    }
    if (!trav) { // If it is null, it is a new letter
        // Create and link in to main list
        trav = new node(alpha);
        trav->next = head;
        head = trav;
    }
    // Create and link into inner list
    node2* newnode = new node2(word, meaning);
    newnode->next = trav->innernode;
    trav->innernode = newnode;
}
```

Note that it is important that `head` is initialized as `node *head = nullptr;`